# How to read this output from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, referential-integrity

Query that is being ran:

```
INSERT INTO `log_url` (`url_id`, `visitor_id`, `visit_time`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Error that is being thrown:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '41721' for key 1
```

Where does `41721` fall into? How do I read this? How do I check the 'key 1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command : `SHOW CREATE TABLE log_url\G`

This will give you a display of the SQL needed to create the table.

It will also show you the indexes and constraints for that table.

The first index (`key 1`) in that table must have a column called `url_id`.

From the error message, you are being told that there exists a row in `log_url` that has `41721` already present. You can verify this with `SELECT * FROM log_url WHERE url_id = 41721;`